# How to calculate hours from varchar2 fields?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, date-arithmetic

I have two varchar2 date fields like clock_in and clock_out. I am inserting datetime by sysdate so the date looks like this:

```
Clock_In                   Clock_Out
12-28-13 08:00 AM          12-28-13 05:00 PM
```

Now I want to calculate the no of hours he work. Can you please help in this matter?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries) - you should **not** store dates as strings - you're just asking for trouble that way. Use the `DATE` or `DATETIME` datatypes!

Comment: @marc_s - there are all sorts of reasons why this sort of thing still happens.  ETL for instance.  Also, interfacing with legacy systems.  Or just a bad decision by the solutions architect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just convert the data to `date`s using the `to_date` function, and then subtract the two values. Since subtracting dates returns a difference in **days**, you can simply multiply by 24 to get the difference in hours:

```
SELECT (TO_DATE(clock_out, 'DD-MM-YY HH:MI AM') - 
        TO_DATE(clock_in, 'DD-MM-YY HH:MI AM')) * 24 AS hours_worked
FROM   my_table
```

EDIT:
An even better solution would probably be to save `clock_in` and `clock_out` as `date` fields to begin with and avoid the hassle of converting in the query, but I'm not sure this is possible for the OP.

Comment: thanks its really helpful for me. I did the same thing as you mention. thanks